# kubectl connectivity to GKE cluster is working from VM but not through Jenkins pipeline from same VM

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, kubectl

I have a linux VM from where I am able to run `kubectl get pods` command without any issue.

I have found out that when I run:

```
gcloud container clusters get-credentials --cluster <cluster-name>
```

command from this VM it stores the kubeconfig file in `$HOME/.kube/config`  as expected.

But when I am running same steps through a jenkins pipeline in same VM, its getting a connection timeout issue to GKE cluster. Also the kubeconfig file's content is same but its path is different this time. It's being created in  the current directory of the pipeline under the name .kube simply. I have also tried passing `--kubeconfig $HOME/.kube/config` in pipeline but its the same issue again.

Answer (score 0):

> I have also tried passing --kubeconfig $HOME/.kube/config in pipeline but its the same issue again.

By specifying `$HOME` variable in a jenkins pipeline you are requesting kube config file from the home dir of a `jenkins user`, for example /var/lib/jenkins.
And:

> Its being created in the current directory of the pipeline under the name .kube

So, the solution is either setting the `KUBECONFIG` environment variable in a jenkins job or setting the `--kubeconfig` flag and pointing them to the existing working kube config file (check the kube config path). See all available jenkins environment variables at
`yourJenkinsUrl:port/env-vars.html`

**EDIT:**

There is a workaround that might be helpful - [**Kubernetes CLI plugin for Jenkins**](https://plugins.jenkins.io/kubernetes-cli/).

> Allows you to configure kubectl in your job to interact with Kubernetes clusters. Any tool built on top of kubectl can then be used from your pipelines to perform deployments, e.g. Shopify/krane.

```json
// Example when used in a pipeline
node {
  stage('Apply Kubernetes files') {
    withKubeConfig([credentialsId: 'user1', serverUrl: 'https://api.k8s.my-company.com']) {
      sh 'kubectl apply -f my-kubernetes-directory'
    }
  }
}
```

How it works?

> The plugin generates a kubeconfig file based on the parameters that were provided in the build. This file is stored in a temporary file inside the build workspace and the exact path can be found in the KUBECONFIG environment variable. kubectl automatically picks up the path from this environment variable. Once the build is finished (or the pipeline block is exited), the temporary kubeconfig file is automatically removed.

Comment: I have tried giving --kubeconfig and giving path to the .kube file being generated by this pipeline job. But same issue again.

Comment: Have you tried the path without variables?

Comment: Yes i hardcoded the path without variables

Comment: @Bajwa, please check my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks for your help on this. The issue was actually related to my Organisation's firewall issue. I am able to resolve this now. Thanks!